# wcf connection timeout retry

Tags: c#, wcf

Below is my WCF connection code. If the connection timesout i would like to retry 3 times. how can i do this?
thanks
damo

**C# Code**

```
                // Get the status from the client machine
                ServiceReference1.JobsClient Client = new ServiceReference1.JobsClient();
                Client.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServicePath"]);
                FactoryAuditEventNotification.ServiceReference1.ReturnClass SystemStatus_Result;
                SystemStatus_Result = Client.SystemState(System.Environment.MachineName);

                if (SystemStatus_Result.ErrorCode < 0) // Error, set the textbox state
                    this.textBoxState.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => this.textBoxState.Text = "Unknown"));
                else
                    this.textBoxState.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => this.textBoxState.Text = "Success"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a for loop ?

```
for(int currentCount = 1;currentCount <= 3;currentCount++)
{
    try
    {
    //your connection logic
    }
    catch(EndpointNotFoundException)
    {
    //throw after three retries
    if(currentCount == 3)
        throw;
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
    //Handle other exceptions as necessary
    }
}
```